# Accessing class definition by name from scala macro

Tags: scala, code-generation, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

I'm trying to create a Scala macro which defines a single a Class argument, and which modifies the class to which it is attached based on the implementation of the Class which is provided as an argument.

```
//Simple class with a few arguments
class A(a: String, b: String)

//Definition of this class should be modified based on class definition of A
@parameterized(classOf[A])
class B
```

I've managed to create a simple macro that is able to extract the argument from the annotation, resulting in a TypeName object that contains a string representation of the full class name.

The problem is now that I need to access the definition of A from the macro implementation (specifically, I want to see what the constructor arguments are).

Is there a way to access/create a TypeTag[A] in some way? Is there a way I can access the AST of class A?

To illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, this is what I currently have as a macro definition:

```
object parameterizedMacro {
  def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    import Flag._      

    //Extract the parameter type which was provided as an argument (rather hacky way of getting this info)
    val parameterType = c.macroApplication match {
      case Apply(Select(Apply(_, List(
          TypeApply(Ident(TermName("classOf")), List(Ident(TypeName(parameterType))))
      )) , _), _) => parameterType
      case _ =>
        sys.error("Could not match @parameterized arguments. Was a class provided?")
    }

   //Should generate method list based on the code of parameterType
   val methods = ???

   val result = {
      annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
        case q"object $name extends ..$parents { ..$body }" :: Nil =>
          q"""
            object $name extends ..$parents {
              ..${methods}
              ..$body
             }
          """
        case q"class $name (..$args) extends ..$parents { ..$body }" :: Nil =>
           q"""
             class $name (..$args) extends ..$parents {
              ..${methods}
               ..$body
             }
          """
      }
    }

    c.Expr[Any](result)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a lot of trial and error, as I didn't manage to find a lot of documentation on the various classes, but I did end up managing to achieve what I wanted to do.

To acquire the parameter, I ended up having to put the fully qualified name in the annotation instead of the original `TypeOf[Name]`.

```
@parameterized(the.fully.qualified.Name)
```

Which I could then get using

```
val parameterType = c.macroApplication match {
      case Apply(Select(Apply(_, List(
          parameterType 
      )) , _), _) => parameterType
      case _ =>
        error("Could not match @parameterized arguments. Was a class provided?")
    }
val fullClassName = parameterType.toString()
```

Using `TypeOf` as mentioned in the original post didn't work for me as I didnt manage to get from the `TypeApply` to the correct fully qualified name. This doesn't really make the whole thing insecure as everything is checked at compile time, but it does look a bit less like standard Scala.

Once I had the fully qualified name, I could use the universe's mirror ([The documentation on mirrors helped here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0-M3/scala-reflect/#scala.reflect.api.Mirrors)) to get a ClassSymbol, from which it is possible to get the class constructor arguments:

```
val constructorArguments = {
  val clazz = c.mirror.staticClass(fullClassName)            //Get ClassSymbol
  val clazzInfo = clazz.info                                 //Turn ClassSymbol into Type
  val constructor = clazzInfo.member(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR)  //Get constructor member Symbol
  val constructorMethod = constructor.asMethod               //Turn into MethodSymbol
  val parametersList = constructorMethod.paramLists          //Finally extract list of parameters

  if (parametersList.size != 1)
    error("Expected only a single constructor in " + fullClassName)

  val parameters = parametersList.head

  for (parameter <- parameters) yield {
    val term = parameter.asTerm //parameter is a term
    (term.name.toString, term.typeSignature)
  }
}
```